# Phpscript to do time countdown not working properly

Tags: php

This script should do the time countdown and stop at the 0 mark but it enters in a weird loop like the one that can be seen in this gif:

https://gyazo.com/0b028a0ff4d597448f02d3ef4985168e

The code:

```
  <?php
@include_once ("set.php");
$game = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");
$r = fetchinfo("starttime","games","id",$game);
if($r == 2147483647) die("120");
$r += 120-time();
if($r < 0) $r = 0;
echo $r;
?>
```

Comment: So I'm assuming that this is an endpoint that's being called repeatedly, probably via javascript? What's calling your endpoint?

Comment: I'm confused, where is the loop in your code? It seems that code is missing

Comment: This is the timeleft.php i tought it would be enough, i dont know what is being called next or anything.